# AQGridViewCell transparent background

Tags: objective-c, ios, transparency, aqgridview

I have a problem customizing my AQGridViewCell. I'd like to have the whole cell having a transparent background, but the following inside of the initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier does not do the job:

```
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
self.contentView.opaque = NO;
self.opaque = NO;
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thank you very much for any response!

**EDIT**
I found [this](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/pull/108#issuecomment-3610006), but this does not seem to work either:
https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/pull/108#issuecomment-3610006

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tip in your [link](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/pull/108#issuecomment-3610006) was half way there. The following did the trick for me:

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = nil;
self.backgroundColor = nil;
```

And you need to put this in your custom AQGridViewCell's `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:`. It's a bit puzzling that you have to set two properties but at least it works.

Also note that you also need to set the background color to `clear` for all text labels you might have, e.g:

```
captionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Setting label background to `nil` doesn't help - it comes out as black.

Comment: Thank you very much! These two properties did it! The labels already were set to clear but thanks anyway :)